# I Cannot Link my jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've looked all around stack overflow for answers to this same problem. Usually it's simple syntax errors like omitting a closing tag or not writing the src attribute properly. 
I could've sworn, though, that my html and js is correct, but I still can't get the jQuery working.

The normal javascript (function test()) works perfectly as it's linked with an html button using onclick. The $('#click') jQuery simply will not work, though.

```
<head>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='jquery-3.2.1.min.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='test.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
    <button type='button' style='margin: 1em;' id='click'>CLICK</button>
    <button type='button' style='margin: 1em;' id='testButton' onclick='test()'>TEST LINKING</button>
</body>
```

Both js files and the html are in the same folder.
And here's the js.test:

```
$('#click').click(function () {
alert('jQuery Works!');
}); //NOT WORKING!

function test() {
alert('Okay!');
} //WORKING!
```

Comment: Gosh... `$(function() { .... });` or `$(document).ready(function() { .... });`

Comment: FANTASTIC! The document.ready worked perfectly. Thank you so much.
So what exactly did I do that made it work?

Comment: You must wrap any jQuery code that is placed **BEFORE** the actual DOM elements, because jQuery try to bind the event listeners for a non-existing elements. Your current code **would** fork only if you load `test.js` **after** the elements (I.e, put it on the bottom, before the closing `</body>` tag)

Comment: And BTW `$(function() { .... });` is a shorthand for  `$(document).ready(function() { .... });`

Comment: I greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Great, not you'll see that there are answers to your question so if they are helpful then please consider accepting one if you find it helpful (There is a "V" icon under every answer that you can click on and it will select that answer as "accepted")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem isn't linking jQuery, it's about scope and DOM loading.

When you create a function globally it becomes a global reference that you can access whenever you want afterward.

When you call a function, or change the value of a variable, it needs a scope to know when to be called. It's generally the global scope but, when you use jQuery functions, you cannot know if your libraries are already loaded and therefore if you'll be able to access the functions they provide.

Therefore, wrap your EH in a `document.ready` function that is executed by jQuery itelf when the DOM is fully loaded. You can do it this way :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#click').click(function () {
    alert('jQuery Works!');
  });
});
```

Or in a shorter way :

```
$(function(){
  $('#click').click(function () {
    alert('jQuery Works!');
  });  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ahh, the problem here is that when you load the JS and jQuery file, browser starts going through you code, finds that it should now bind a click handler for `#click`, but when it actually goes to find `#click` on the page it doesn't get it. Because it has not been added to the dom yet !

You have three ways to deal with this :

1. Use the `defer` attribute of the script tag. It is used to define script that will not run until after the page has loaded

   ```
   <script type='text/javascript' src='test.js' defer></script>
   ```
2. Just load your JS for the event handler after the divs like :

   `<head>
     <script type='text/javascript' src='jquery-3.2.1.min.js'></script>
   </head>
   <body>
     <button type='button' style='margin: 1em;' id='click'>CLICK</button>
     <button type='button' style='margin: 1em;' id='testButton' onclick='test()'>TEST LINKING</button>
     <script type='text/javascript' src='test.js'></script>
   </body>`

This is why you normally see the line

> Place CSS includes in the head and JS include just before the close of the `body` tag

That's because without CSS your page would look ugly untill it has been loaded, and placing JS in the end would make sure that the DOM is in place for any action to be performed on it

3. You can use the `$(document).ready(function(){ ... })` event handler. This event is triggered when the document is ready or essentially when the dom has been created. Binding you click handler here makes sure that the elem is actually available for your JS to bind to

Answer (score 0):

You cant define a function in a way like this. you need to do this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#click').click(function() {
    alert('jQuery Works!');
    //declare other function
  });
});
```

`